# Passing Application class to a static field

Tags: java, javafx

In my code, I want to make a JavaFX Application runnable from wherever via a sort of wrapper class. I attempted to accomplish this by passing the Application object to a static field in the wrapper class, but when I call `launch()`, it (I assume) continues the thread until `stop()` is called, rendering the rest of my code in the wrapper unreachable for all intents and purposes. Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way? Here's my code:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    public void start(Stage s) {
        Wrapper.application = this;
    }
}

public class Wrapper {
    public MyApp application = null;
    public Wrapper() {
        MyApp.launch(MyApp.class);
        System.out.println("Launched!");
        //do other things
    }
}
```

The code reaches everything until after `launch()`, (it never prints `Launched!`) and I can't figure out how to get around that.

Comment: What is the purpose of the wrapper ?

Comment: And from where (which thread) is the constructor of `Wrapper` called?

Comment: The [documentation for the `launch(...)` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#launch-java.lang.String...-) explicitly states that it does not exit until the JavaFX platform exits. Why not just move `//do other things` to the end of the `start(...)` method?